# GeoDjango distance queries returning incorrect results

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I just got GeoDjango up and running on my development machine. Problem is that I can't get a distance query to work correctly. No matter what SRID I use, the distance results are totally off. Here's an example.

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
>>> from app.models import Place
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
>>> qs = Place.objects.all()
>>> point = Point(-118, 34)
>>> qs.filter(coordinates__distance_lte=(point, D(m=1)))
[<Place: 7-Eleven>, <Place: Arthur Murray Dance Studio>, <Place: Costco>, <Place: AMC Century City 15>, <Place: 24 Hour Fitness>, <Place: Ralphs>, <Place: Houston's Restaurant>, <Place: CVS/pharmacy>, <Place: Shaky Alibi>, <Place: Sephora>, <Place: Trader Joe's>]
```

The problem is that these places are much further than 1m away from `point`.

I tried playing around with it, but haven't had much luck. Here's an example with another SRID.

```
>>> qs = Place.objects.all().transform(3786)
>>> point = Point(-118, 34, srid=3786)
>>> qs.filter(coordinates__distance_lte=(point, D(m=1)))
[<Place: 7-Eleven>, <Place: Arthur Murray Dance Studio>, <Place: Costco>, <Place: AMC Century City 15>, <Place: 24 Hour Fitness>, <Place: Ralphs>, <Place: Houston's Restaurant>, <Place: CVS/pharmacy>, <Place: Shaky Alibi>, <Place: Sephora>, <Place: Trader Joe's>]
```

I have a feeling I'm just choosing the wrong SRIDs, but not a single one that I've run into online has worked, or given any response that is even moderately useful.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you might want to try asking here http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up...didn't realize that StackExchange had a site for GIS-related questions. Wondering if I should keep it here, or wait for a mod to move it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hate to be answering my own question, but no one else stepped up to the plate and I figured out the solution.

I delved into PostGIS to isolate the issue to either the location database itself or to Django. So I converted the Django ORM query I had been using above into the ideal query that I would have expected the PostGIS backend to receive. To my surprise, the query that was being produced was equivalent to:

```
SELECT id
FROM app_place
WHERE ST_DWithin(coordinates, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-118, 34), 3768), 1);
```

That was the problem right there. The query I needed was:

```
SELECT id
FROM app_place
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-118, 34), 3768), coordinates) < 1;
```

I read through the Django source to figure out what was happening here, and I realized that I had set `geography=True` on my `coordinates` field. Apparently, this changes the PostGIS functions Django generates when creating the SQL query. It's undocumented, but here is the [relevant section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#geography-type).

In short, if you're having this issue, remove `geography=True` from your model and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi dan, I've got a similar problem: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14232/using-a-geodjango-pointfield-with-geograph-true-my-distance-calculations-are-6-o. In theory the distance calculations should be more accurate under geography=True and use the ST_Distance_Spheroid. Any suggestions (other than just removing geography=True, which will take me back to square one...) would be most helpful. Thanks